# Interfaces named with `ge` represent what?

Tags: interface

I see a information:

```
Most interfaces are named according to:
 - Interface media type (ge, so, at, and so forth)
...
```

I know the `so` represent `SONET`, `at` represnet `ATM`, but how about the `ge` ? if it means the `ethernet`, why not `et`?

Comment: Gigabit Ethernet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you're asking about JunOS, the Operating System of Juniper for their hardware.

ge means Gigabit Ethernet.

This a list of ethernet interfaces and names used in JunOS:

`ae`— Aggregated Ethernet interface.

`et`— 100-Gigabit Ethernet interfaces.

`fe`— Fast Ethernet interface.

`ge`— Gigabit Ethernet interface.

`xe`— 10-Gigabit Ethernet interface.

For a complete list click [here](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/concept/interfaces-interface-naming-overview.html)

Answer (score 3):

It means `Gigabit Ethernet`.

See more in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet)

Answer (score 0):

G is mainly represent the Bandwidth of port/interface that means 1000 Mega bits per seconds where as E for Ethernet technology. So, port name written as Gigabit Ethernet as per IEEE standards, Now 10GE and 100GE interfaces are also deployed in production environment.